# PHP CMS - How to 'Creating New Page' works

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn, how to make a php content management system. I'm watching tutorials and reading documents about that but I couldn't understand something. For example there is 5 different page design.

1. Home Design
2. About Us Design
3. Products Design
4. Gallery Design
5. Contact Design

When I click new page button what should happen backside. Should it create a new php file or just insert a new line to the database. And for example when I want to create products pages at 3 different category. Should I need 3 products.php file or just one file for products design. And when I want to add a page should I design 5 different admin interface for each page? Actually I am not asking for code. I just want to learn the best way to do these things.

Thanks all :)

Comment: `just insert a new line` and `just one file for products design` and `design 5 different admin interface`

Comment: downlaod and look at the source code of any CMS. you will learn more that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a table in your database, call it "pages" and add columns:

- id
- title
- content
- published_date
- status

and any other.

Then pass the page id via url (?p=123) and use query to show the relevant page via database.

Comment: Is to use GET secure for this process?

Comment: yes, you'll be using $_GET['p'];

Comment: please upvote and mark this ans as correct (if it helped :) )

Comment: you're welcome friend :)

Comment: It won't be secure if you don't prevent SQL Injection - which simply using `$_GET['p']` on it's own will **not** protect you against.

Comment: obviously, he needs to learn about securing incoming requests too and how to filter them :)